# Как узнать в каком столбце (их 51)?

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день. У меня есть таблица items. В ней по иду пользователя находим ид столбика, который принадлежит пользователю. Вопрос: нужно узнать в каком столбике item0...item51 (данные записываются рандомно в них) находится предмет (запись там такая : 50|100 50 это айди, 100 количество ) и вывести количество, то есть, которое в столбце.
И ещё один вопрос:
Нужно найти все (в тех столбцах) данные 54|имя и написать количество найденных или слово "есть".[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ид ровняться иду аккаунта, то есть нужно искать по иду ещё чтоб совпали, то есть что это его инвентарь

Comment: Меняйте структуру свой таблицы. Случайные столбики это очень странно ;)

Comment: Все равно меняйте. делайте вторую таблицу в которую из первой триггерами будут переноситься данные при записи. хотя в триггере все равно придется перебрать все поля. Или лучше вытягивайте всю запись на клиента и там ищите, там то уже массив будет

Comment: ну или concat сначала соберите все колонки вместе, а потом в этом большом текстовом поле ищите нужное

Comment: А через лайк %текст% как-то нельзя?

Comment: наверняка можно, но сначала все равно придется собрать в одну колонку все

Comment: Есть пример как это сделать? Буду благодарен)

Comment: Нароод, хоть кто-то что-то подскажите ещё))

Comment: Скиньте структуру таблицы, и данные как там записаны, а то не очень понятно

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно, и нету дело до производительности.
То вам поможет функция [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/String_functions.html)

```
-- Получение 50 то что до |
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('50|100', '|', 1);

-- Получение 100 то что после |
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('50|100', '|', -1)

для поиска в запросе можете тоже использовать что-то вроде
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX('50|100', '|', 1) = 50
```

В место `'50|100'` подставляете колонку (примерный код)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(Item0, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(Item1, '|', -1) FROM table t 
    WHERE ID = ИД пользователя
```

Comment: Эта функция пробегается по 51у столбцу и находит то,что мне нужно? И как правильно вывести это значение?) Ну то,что после 50|?

Comment: Если привидёте пример вашей таблицы и их данных, с могу точно написать. А так `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('50|100', '|', -1);` Получение то что после |, в данном случаи это 100

Comment: Могу скриншот структуры и данных в ней прислать куда-то?

Comment: Вопрос отредактируйте, добавьте туда. Так будет нагляднее и для других

Comment: Добавил, проверьте)

Comment: Да в принципе поможет, добавьте в выражение свою таблицу. В Выборку добавьте поиск по ID. А в selecte, нужно будет для каждой колонки прописать SUBSTRING_INDEX(item0, '|', -1) и так далее

Comment: Вывод такой уже не катит? $row['']?

Comment: Насчет вывода не знаю, можно добавит алиасы к запросу, или же обращатся по номеру строк

Comment: -1 в конце это поиск первой строчки,что до черточки? И можно ли все в скобках сделать и за ними =50?

Comment: И как вывести "есть" при поиске 54/ник?

Comment: Вы посмотрите документацию, ссылку привёл, данная функция обрезает по разделителю, можно так же обрезать `54/ник`, в данном случаи разделитель будет `/`

Comment: `-1` - он ищет первое совпадение с конца. Таким образом в примере `50|100` он ищет первое `|` с конца и возвращяет то что нашел это `100`. Если число положительное то он вернет `50`

Comment: Спасибо большое вам)

Comment: То есть , если хочу найти айди 50 число положительное?) Извините за повторение)

Comment: Да, так и есть, `50|100`. При положительном он будет искать с начало