# Мне нужно вывести результат, который нашел substing index

Tags: php, mysql

[Как узнать в каком столбце (их 51)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/728117/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%85-51) - вот тема где решили проблему с нахождением значения, но теперь возникла проблема с выводом этого значения, как это можно сделать?
Вот этот код `querymoney = mysql_query("SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(item0, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item1, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item2, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item3, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item4, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item5, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item6, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item7, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item8, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item9, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item10, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item11, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item12, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item13, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item14, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item15, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item16, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item17, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item18, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item19, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item20, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item21, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item22, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item23, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item24, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item25, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item26, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item27, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item28, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item29, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item30, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item31, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item32, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item33, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item34, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item35, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item36, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item37, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item38, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item39, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item40, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item41, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item42, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item43, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item44, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item45, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item46, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item47, '|', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(item48, '|', -1) FROM`items`where`ID`= '$row[ID]' OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item0', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item1', '|', 1) =50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item2', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item3', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item4', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item5', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item6', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item7', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item8', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item9', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item10', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item11', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item12', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item13', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item14', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item15', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item16', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item17', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item18', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item19', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item20', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item21', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item22', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item23', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item24', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item25', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item26', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item27', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item28', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item29', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item30', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item31', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item32', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item33', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item34', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item35', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item36', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item37', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item38', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item39', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item40', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item41', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item42', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item43', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item44', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item45', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item46', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item47', '|', 1) = 50 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX('item48', '|', 1) = 50`

Comment: А что по вашему сейчас возвращает этот запрос, он как раз и возвращает требуемое значение. значение на экран обычно выводится с помощью `echo` или `print`. в чем вопрос то состоит

Comment: Просто мне же нужно указать из какого столбца вывести, а я не знаю, тк рандомная система

Comment: но ведь вам возвращается массив значений. обойдите этот массив foreach и найдите заполненное. хотя лично я бы выбросил все эти дурацкие subsring_index из части select и сделал бы просто `select *` а значение нашел бы при этом самом обходе в цикле на php, оно бы в разы короче было и не грузило бы БД неспецифичными для нее операциями

Comment: @Mike сможете помочь с примерным циклом? ну ваша идея более лучшая. И то есть, мне в селект запрос не нужно будет перечислять таблицы все?

Comment: ну в части where придется, хотя я бы по другому и в нем сделал, но перечисление все равно бы осталось. А в части select просто `*`. Вот смотрите у вас на php есть массив `$arr=array('a', 'b','c',...)` вы же надеюсь знаете как обойти элементы этого массива foreach ? вот, теперь представте что эти элементы не abc, а вроде '50|100'. вы знаете как на php разделить значение этой переменной на две части с помощью explode ? после этого у вас есть левая и правая часть, остается сделать `IF($x[0]==50) echo $x[1]`

Comment: @Mike типо такого? `for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) { 
//тут отправляем запрос
//тут проверяем на предмет
}`

Comment: нет, отправляете запрос. потом читаете строку с помощью `mysql_fetch_array($querymoney, MYSQL_NUM)` все, у вас на руках массив значений всех столбцов которые вернул запрос, т.е. вот тот самый массив `['1|11','2|12','50|100',...]` обходите его foreach. И почитайте что такое foreach, он ну совершенно не for, который вы почему то захотели использовать вместо него

Comment: Как это реализовать? Есть пример у кого-то?